# How to compare symbols alphabetically in Common Lisp?

Tags: compare, common-lisp

I trying to compare a symbol to another alphabetically, but I can't do this.
In particular, I've done this.

```
CL-USER 1 > (string-lessp 'k 'a)
NIL

CL-USER 2 > (string-lessp 'a 'k)
0
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: @jkiiski If you're accustomed to "C-style" languages, the `0` looks like false, when it's just an accidentally confusing true value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Common Lisp,  NIL is false, and anything else is true.  So in your transcript,  0 is a true value, indicating that A is before K. Rather than simply returning T and NIL, [STRING-LESSP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) returns a mismatch index:

> The inequality functions return a mismatch-index that is true if the strings are not equal, or false otherwise. When the mismatch-index is true, it is an integer representing the first character position at which the two substrings differ, as an offset from the beginning of string1.

0 is the index of the first character where the designated strings don't agree.